# change table column and row style on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write the script to change the style of a table column and row on hover. This script works when I have one table in the page, but does not work for others. I know that I need to grab all tables with `.price_table` class but I'm new in jQuery, Pleas help me

```
$(function() {           
$(".price_table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    }
}); });
```

i cant put my table hear the system says "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted", but it is a simple table, he only difference is that it contains `<colgroup></colgroup>` tags as many as columns in the table

Comment: Have you tried to _grab all tables with .price_table class_?? just give all tables the same class.

Comment: Please kindly show your HTML.

Comment: @dfsq Er... That's why deleted bro!

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki  I did , doesnt work

Comment: Okay post your HTML please.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki  this is the link of my site  page http://sprint.tmweb.ru/my-dealem/pechat/businesscard.html

Comment: @Arno check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not in CSS but in your HTML, you can see in screenshot bellow that the `colgroup`s in table aren't defined correctely:

[image]

Comment: @akaria Acharki sorry but I can't see the problem

Comment: @akaria Acharki  this is where I found this code https://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-three.php